# Restart CMD process within cronjob

Tags: docker, dockerfile

My docker command has the following `CMD`:

```
CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

Every week, my container must perform a command (preferably via `cron`). After the command succeeds, I must restart the process that started via `CMD`.

How would I restart the `CMD` process from within a container in docker?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `docker exec <containername> npm restart` from your cron

Regards